# How can I add custom field to editing wordpress category?

Tags: wordpress

How can I add custom field (Second SEO-description) to taxonomy editor?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8736/add-custom-field-to-category

Answer (score 0):

Try the plugin WordPress SEO by Yoast. this will get you some control over the Category meta.
https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/

Or if you really want meta data for each Cat. try Category Meta plugin.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-category-meta/